# Selecting one item to slide down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list of tasks pulled from a MySQL DB as shown here:

```
echo '<li>';
echo '<span><a id="'.$task_id.'" class="task">'.$task_name.'</a></span>';

echo '<input type="checkbox" class="favourite" name="favourite" id="'.$task_id.'" + '.$favouriteChecked.' "> '; 

echo '<img id="'.$task_id.'" class="delete-button" width="10px" src="images/close.svg" />';
echo '</li>';

echo '<form class="add-additional-info" id="'.$task_id.'+additionalinfo"autocomplete="off">';
echo '<input type="text" name="new-info" placeholder="Add extra info" />';
echo '</form>';
```

When somebody clicks on a class="task" I have the following code to slide down into a new a text box

```
function slide_task() {
            // On tap or hover, have a text box that slides down to enter extra information.
            var hiddenContent = $( ".add-additional-info" );

            $('.task').click(function() {
                    event.preventDefault();
                     if (hiddenContent.is( ":visible" )){
                        hiddenContent.slideUp( 600 );
                    } else {
                        hiddenContent.slideDown( 600 );
                    }

            });
```

Which links to the following CSS

```
.add-additional-info{
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    display: none;
}

.add-additional-info input[type='text'] {
    width: 100%;
    font: normal 1.2em 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #999;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #ddd;
    border: none;
    border-radius: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 12px 6%;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

What the code does currently is SlideDown a text box under every single one of the 'task' classes. What I want to happen is only have it slide down under the 'task' that has been clicked.

I also need to be able to submit the information entered into the the text box to a MySQL DB - I think being able to use a unique identifier for each task (the ID?) will solve both these issues. Perhaps using "'.$task_id.'+additionalinfo"?

I know there is a simple solution there somewhere but I'm not what should go where.

EDIT: Cleaned up code and added a unique ID to each add-additonal-info

Comment: When you post something on snippets it should work (at least something). none of these work.

Comment: This question is rather poorly formatted.  If you want to just show code without creating runnable snippets, use the "Code Sample (Ctrl+K)" button in the editor rather than the "Snippet" one.

Comment: IMG and checkbox have the same ID. Any HTML ID should be there only once.

Comment: I thought snippets were just for easily inserting code. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

To slide down the next `.add-additional-info` to the parent `li` of the clikced `.task` you should do.

```
        $('.task').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).closest("li").nextUntil(".add-additional-info").slideToggle(600);

        });
```

`closest()` traverse upwards and return the first `li`, `nextUntil()` will get the next `.add-additional-info` element, and `slideToggle` will take care of sliding upwards or downwards, whatever required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the slide effect only to the form that follows directly beneath the task that was clicked on. Right now, you're applying it to all of them. Based on your HTML, you could modify your click function to be like:

```
function slide_task() {
        // On tap or hover, have a text box that slides down to enter extra information.
        $('.task').click(function() {
                event.preventDefault();
                var hiddenContent = $(this).parent().parent().next();
                 if (hiddenContent.is( ":visible" )){
                    hiddenContent.slideUp( 600 );
                } else {
                    hiddenContent.slideDown( 600 );
                }

        });
```

The `$(this).parent().parent().next()` Moves from the `.task` link, to the span, to the li, and then to the element directly following the li, which is your `.add-additional-info` form. This solution is completely dependent on your HTML structure, and if that changes, it will break.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately it didn't seem to work, however I've edited my response to give each 'add-additional-info' entry a unique ID. Is it possible to use that unique ID to have less fragile code?